# Why won't Ubuntu installed using Wubi accept my password?

Tags: wubi, password

I can boot into Ubuntu just fine as a guest but it refuses to accept my login name and password that were set during the Wubi install. I reinstalled it again with basic login and password just to make sure and it still won't let me in.

Comment: Note that Wubi uses the Windows account as the login name for the Wubi install, and the name you chose for the actual Ubuntu username. So are you entering the password you entered with the Ubuntu username or the one associated with the Windows account name?

Answer (score 1):

There have been some reports of this. It's not clear what the cause is, but you can try resetting the password as follows:

1. After selecting `Ubuntu` hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key until the `Grub` menu appears. If you're using Windows 8, the computer will restart - in this case as soon as the `BIOS` screen disappears hold down then <kbd>Shift</kbd> key.
2. Select the second entry, `Advanced Options`.
3. Again, select the second entry for `Recovery mode`. It will boot to a recovery menu.
4. Select `Remount drives as read/write`
5. Select `Root shell`
6. Check your username by entering:

   `ls /home`
7. Reset your password (replacing  with your Ubuntu username which you saw under /home):

   `passwd <username>`
8. Enter `exit` to leave the shell and then select `Resume normal boot`

e.g.

```
root@ubuntu:~# ls /home
bcbc
root@ubuntu:~# passwd bcbc
Enter new UNIX password:
Retype new UNIX password:
```