# Install incorect password

Tags: 12.04, installation, password

When I try yo use wubi, to install Ubuntu 12.04, side by side with Windows 7, I get an incorrect password error.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific, please? What steps did you take during the installation and at what point does the error appear?

Answer (score 0):

*I should tell you that we are are Off Topic, because this web site is only for Ubuntu OS related problems*.
The password to login in Ubuntu (or other Ubuntu distros) is the **same** of the Wubi installer. The password in Linux is always **case sensitive** like the username.
Your Windows account is **different** from you Wubi distro account.
The problem was already solved [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256297/cannot-log-in-to-wubi-installed-ubuntu). Hope you'll solve, feel free to ask if in doubt.