# How do I get Super User access in guest

Tags: permissions, sudo, root

I have recently installed Ubuntu via Wubi Installer. The dual-boot works fine but when I can't login as Admin, it only allows me to enter via "Guest".

To do any administrative activities such setting up Network or create another user it asks for Root or super user password. 
How can I create a Super User or enable it. I have see few videos where the password can be enbaled via Restart and then Recovery Mode. When I restart my machine nothing happens may be because its Dual Boot with Windows.

Can anyone help me how to do I setup a Super User or steps that I need to follow.

Comment: Tried the answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/256297/why-wont-ubuntu-installed-using-wubi-accept-my-password?

Comment: Grub menu doesnt come......tried pressing shift number of times nothing happens....i can only login to Guest user

Comment: Try this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/362528/sudo-not-available-in-guest-login